# Avoid struct padding in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures, struct

In my code, I have the following `struct`:

```
struct foo {
 int a;
 int b;
};
```

In `b`, only values between 0 and 100 are stored. So in general, I could replace it by a `char`. But than the size of the `struct` is the same due to padding effects. As my code contains `vectors` and `sets` of these structure with several million entries, it would bring the memory usage down by more than one third if I could circumvent padding in some way. Is there any possibility to do this, e.g. some other (boost) data container which behaves in the same way?

Edit:
I use both, the GNU and the Intel compiler on Linux systems:

Comment: You need a `struct` `pack`-ing. Depends on your compiler, you may use (probably `pragma pack`) to tell your compiler, not to add padding.

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0150/

Comment: @Kiril Why did you not add this as an answer?

Comment: @Ant - because I can't test it for sure right now and it depends on the compiler, which is not written in the question (I mean, I don't know the compiler to give an exact answer). Also, I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate of this question, I'll try to find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ struct alignment question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455458/c-struct-alignment-question)

Comment: @Kiril: I just tested it with a GNU compiler, and it works. Now I have to see, how the performance is influenced when accessing the data.

Comment: @Kiril thank you. It's so compiler dependent that I thought that was a sufficient and correct answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could split your struct in two.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer :)

Comment: Do you really **need** to pack it?  Most processors are more efficient with the native size (integer) than a smaller size.  Also, there may be extra processing time required to handle the smaller sizes; check your assembly code.  *Is the packing going to save you huge amounts of memory space?*

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I made some benchmarks: The part of my code, which works on this data is around 10% slower with the packed data. But this part takes just 1% of the overall runtime, so the extra slowdown does not really matter. But, the data is responsible for more than 30% of the code's memory usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>Moving my comment as an answer, as the community advised :)</sub>

This is compiler dependent. What you need is to use `struct` `pack`ing.

For Visual Studio, you need `#pragma pack` and for `gcc`, you need to use an attribute `packed`.

For more information, see [C++ struct alignment question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455458/c-struct-alignment-question)

<sub>Hope that helps, sorry I can't really test it right now, but that's what you need</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Short of using special `#pragma`s to control the structure padding/alignment, you could split `a` and `b` and store them in *separate* `vector`s, and "match" them by index.

As for `set`s, even if you could easily split the structure to its constituent parts (which you probably can't from the purely logical perspective - `set`s don't have indexes), you'd still pay for dynamic memory management alignment which would likely erase any advantage you might have gained with that.