# Allocate the memory of struct more efficiently in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying the construct a struct in C++ as below:

```
struct kmer_value {
    uint32_t count : 32;
    uint32_t  path_length : 32;
    uint8_t acgt_prev : 4;
    uint8_t  acgt_next : 4;
}
```

The struct currently takes the memory of 12 bytes, but I want to reduce the size to 9 bytes. Is there any way to realize it?

Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh `acgt_prev` and `acgt_next` share  `uint8_t`

Comment: Sure, just compress the dynamic range of `count` or `path_length`.  If they don't each need 32 bits, allocate fewer for each.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3318475/489590

Comment: see this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455458/c-struct-alignment-question

Comment: What does `uint32_t count : 32;` do that `uint32_t count;` doesn't?

Comment: What's the use case where there will be benefit having the struct not end on a word boundary?

Comment: @Borgleader You wouldn't believe me if I told you. Those first 23 bits... wow.

Comment: @user4581301 What about those first *23* bits? I honestly don't know what you're on about.

Answer (score 9):

There's no portable solution. For GCC that would be

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) kmer_value {
  uint32_t count : 32;
  uint32_t path_length : 32;
  uint8_t acgt_prev : 4;
  uint8_t acgt_next : 4;
};
```

In MSVC `#pragma pack` can achieve the same effect.

Consult your compiler's documentation.